# Analysis of a game algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, analysis

I am relatively new to JavaScript and trying to improve, so I was practicing and solving some challenging questions on CodeFights, this is the link: https://codefights.com/challenge/5woihS52FBamZvyYg 
(I didn't want to copy the problem all the way to here)

I've tried couple of times but failed, then I gave up and started to wait for time-is-up to see the solutions.

This one is the shortest solution for JavaScript:

```
/* CREDITS TO "sinpamov" */

function target_game(a) {    
    b = t = 0
    for (i in a) {
        c = b + a[i]
        b = t
        t = c > t ? c : t
    }
    return t
}
```

Of course, the author tried to shorten everything to get the shortest solution, I get it. I have no problem with understanding the syntax here. But semantically... I don't get how this algorithm works and how to analyze it. I would appreciate every crystal clear explanation, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Let's say TheListofGameYouWantToInsert contains
//index 0 •Assasin's Creed 2    or 2
//index 1 •FallOut 4            or 4
//index 2 •Batman Arkham Knight or 1


function target_game(TheListofGameYouWantToInsert) {    
    b = t = 0
    //b = 0 and t = 0 why? because b and t are empty and only the "0" is a defined value which will prioritize first
    // What will happen would be t is also 0 because b = t where t is 0
    //b = (t = 0);
    //b = (0 = 0);
    //b = 0;
    for (index in TheListofGameYouWantToInsert) {  
    //for everytime the code runs on each list of "TheListofGameYouWantToInsert"
    //index usually starts with 0;  
        c = b + a[i] 
        //c is equal to b which is 0 and add TheListofGameYouWantToInsert[index]
        //c = 0 + TheListofGameYouWantToInsert[0]
        //c = 0 + 2      the Assasin's Creed 2
        //c =(0 + 2)
        //c = 2;
        b = t
        //b is again became t which is 0
        //b = 0
        t = c > t ? c : t
        //t is equal to whichever makes the condition true
        //t = is c greater than t? if yes then give c or if not, then give t
        //t = is 2 greater that 0? if yes return 2 or if not, return 0
        //t = 2 > 0? 2 : 0
        //t = 2;
    }
    return t // output 2 
}

//Next Index which is 1
        c = b + a[i] 
        //c = 0 + TheListofGameYouWantToInsert[1]
        //c = 0 + 4      the FallOut 4
        //c =(0 + 4)
        //c = 4;
        b = t
        //b is again became t which is 0
        //b = 0
        t = c > t ? c : t
        //t = 4 > 0? 4 : 0
        //t = 4;

//Next Index which is 2
        c = b + a[i] 
        //c = 0 + TheListofGameYouWantToInsert[2]
        //c = 0 + 1      the Batman Arkham Knight 1
        //c =(0 + 1)
        //c = 1;
        b = t
        //b is again became t which is 0
        //b = 0
        t = c > t ? c : t
        //t = 1 > 0? 1 : 0
        //t = 1;
        
//Until the last list is processed
```

Comment: Maybe I've chosen wrong words to explain myself. I understand what every line of code does and I'm able to track every variable. What I don't understand is "why". Why does this code give the optimum result? How is it designed? For example why the coder wrote `c = b + a[i]`? What is the logic and thinking behind it?